# python matplotlib how to open an image with class

Tags: python, image, class, matplotlib

I'm pretty new with matplotlib and I tried to write a class to open and close image through matplotlib, here is the code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ptlShow():
    def __init__(self, file, pos):
        plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 1.4))
        fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)

        ax.axis("off")

        im = plt.imread(file)
        ax.imshow(im)


        fig.canvas.manager.window.overrideredirect(1)
        plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry(pos)#  
        plt.show()

    def close(self):
        plt.close




a = ptlShow('1.jpg', '+700+100')
b = ptlShow('2.jpg', '+500+100')

a.close()
b.close()
```

but finally I have only one instance of image and close doesn't work, what I'm doing wrong ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.show()` is meant to be called exactly once at the end of the script as it takes over the event loop. Code coming after that is not executed until all figures are closed.

You would probably want to close a figure by clicking on it, so you can register the close method to a `button_press_event`. Note that `plt.close` is just the function - you would want to call it: `plt.close()`.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ptlShow():
    def __init__(self, file, pos):
        plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

        self.fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 1.4))
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)

        ax.axis("off")

        im = plt.imread(file)
        ax.imshow(im)

        self.fig.canvas.manager.window.overrideredirect(1)
        self.fig.canvas.manager.window.wm_geometry(pos)# 
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.close)

    def close(self, event=None):
        plt.close(self.fig)

a = ptlShow('1.jpg', '+700+100')
b = ptlShow('2.jpg', '+500+100')

plt.show()
```

In order to close the window after some time t, you can use `tkinter`s `.after` method, `.after(t, func)`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ptlShow():
    def __init__(self, file, pos):
        plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

        self.fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 1.4))
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)

        ax.axis("off")

        im = plt.imread(file)
        ax.imshow(im)


        self.fig.canvas.manager.window.overrideredirect(1)
        self.fig.canvas.manager.window.wm_geometry(pos)# 
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.close)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("draw_event", self.delayed_close)

    def delayed_close(self,event=None):
        self.fig.canvas.manager.window.after(1000, self.close)
    def close(self, event=None):
        plt.close(self.fig)

a = ptlShow('house.png', '+700+100')
b = ptlShow('house.png', '+500+100')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! OK, but how I can close 'a' image ?

Comment: By clicking on it.

Comment: For sure, but in my case I need to do it by code! As you can see I have no border with image ! Maybe I can simulate key press???

Comment: Well you could show it and then close it, which would essentially mean that you do not see it at all; but I guess this is not what you mean?

Comment: I need to show and close images by code without user interaction !

Comment: Please be specific. If you show the image and then close it, the user will not even see the image, because it is closed before he can blink his eyes. So what exactly do you want?

Comment: Exactly ))) But in my implementation the code will wait some time before closing images !)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and assistance !!! Can you please also share the code how to close image via some (event) or function ! Appreciated !

Comment: The above *is* the code to close the figure window for some event.

Comment: So, is it work for you ? I can not realize it ? The images doesn't appear, with your last update  !

Comment: Yes, it works. The images are shown and closed automatically 1 second after they are shown.

Comment: Hhhm, very strange, could you share the full code !

Comment: Thanks, so finally I can not manipulate each image separately??? (I mean close one by one ) plt.close function works for all open windows ?

Comment: `plt.close(fig)` closes `fig`, `plt.close("all")` closes all figures.

Comment: like this?: 

a = ptlShow('1.jpg', '+700+100')
b = ptlShow('2.png', '+500+100')

plt.show()
plt.close('all')

But it doesn't work, images still appears

Comment: The first sentence of my answer explains why.